# Code and suffix for retina universal iPhone apps?

Tags: xcode, retina-display, ios-universal-app

I am planning to make a universal app to support retina display. It will be a quiz with more than 100 questions. So, for the bg images the suffix will be:  iPhone, iPod:320X480 = photo.png, retina iPhone, iPod: 640X960 = photo@2x.png     iPad: 1024X748 = photo~ipad.png  and for retina iPad 2048 X 1496 (apple doc?) (1536?) = photo@2x~ipad.png . Do I need to write any additional code? Would it be too much to include 4 images for every question, that means 4 images X 120 questions = 480 images!!!Would it be to heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suffix the OS is looking for is "`@2x.png`"

So if you want to do separate graphics for iPhone versus iPad, put those differences in their filenames *before* the `@2x` part.

And yeah, four images does seem a bit like overkill.  Why not just simply have regular resolution image and a high resolution image for various UI widgets used in *both* your iPad and iPhone versions?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand, you suggest to make 2 bg images instead of 4? What resolution they will be?

Comment: This probably depends on how you're designing your app overall, but if I had two separate XIB files (one for iPhone, the other for iPad), then **YES**, I might have two "bg" (background?) images for each XIB file (or four in total, if there are two separate XIB or storyboard files). My original answer was talking about UI widgets (like images used within controls), and then you could just have two images ("regular" resolution and retina high rez).

Comment: I planning to work with one XIB file and creating background images  (Wholes images with buttons ,e.g. ducks, birds or words),4 images for each question.

Comment: Do you mean, creating only 2 images for buttons?

Comment: The usual set-up is to have one XIB file per architecture (i.e. one for iPad, another for iPhone & iPod Touch).  Why not just have the two XIB files and two images (one low, one high-rez) for the buttons?

Comment: You mean one image for iPad and one for iPod/phone? What resolutions should I use for high and low?